# building a hex value from integers

Tags: java

i am trying to generate a hex color value from an integer input, and I'm not sure I'm using the concat method correctly. when i output the string theColor, i only get "0x", any ideas?

```
public String generateColor(String redVal, String blueVal, 
  String greenVal, String alphaVal){
      String theColor = "0x";

      theColor.concat(alphaVal);
      theColor.concat(redVal);
      theColor.concat(greenVal);
      theColor.concat(blueVal);

      return theColor;
}
```

Comment: I see what you're trying to do here, but if you have a Java `Color` class, you can call `getRGB()` on it and then just convert the integer as a single value.

Comment: In Java `String` objects are **immutable**.

Comment: @markspace has the best solution here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String's `concat` does not modify the original String (Strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) in Java). I'd suggest using a `StringBuilder` here:

```
public String generateColor(String redVal, String blueVal, String greenVal, String alphaVal) {
    StringBuilder theColor = new StringBuilder("0x")
            .append(alphaVal)
            .append(redVal)
            .append(greenVal)
            .append(blueVal);
    return theColor.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to reassign it to the theColor as concat() method returns a string with concatenation.

like

```
theColor = theColor.concat(alphaVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

String objects in java are immutable that is operations like `concat` do not modify original object but create new. You need modify you code to assign modified value to `theColor`:

```
theColor = theColor.concat(alphaVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input strings are all 2-character strings with two hex digits, then you can generate the string you want really simply:

```
 public String generateColor(String redVal, String blueVal, 
                             String greenVal, String alphaVal) {
     return "0x" + alphaVal + redVal + greenVal + blueVal;
 }
```

No need to fool around with `StringBuilder` or `concat`.

If the input strings have been converted from integers, so that you're not sure that they are two hex digits, then the above won't work.  But solutions using `concat` or `StringBuilder`'s `append` won't work either, since they essentially do the same thing as `+` -- they just concatenate all the strings together.

The first question to ask is, are you converting the integers to Strings too early?  If you convert the integers to strings, then you pass the strings as parameters to `generateColor`, and then you are concerned that the strings aren't already in the right format, then you really ought to be passing your **integers** to `generateColor`, instead of the strings, and letting `generateColor` convert them to the kinds of strings you need.  There are several ways to do this; here's one:

```
 public String generateColor(int redVal, int blueVal, 
                             int greenVal, int alphaVal) {
     return String.format("0x%02x%02x%02x%02x", alphaVal & 0xFF,
         redVal & 0xFF, greenVal & 0xFF, blueVal & 0xFF);
 }
```

`%02x` says to format the next parameter in hex (the `x`), into a string 2 characters wide (the `2`), and padding with leading zeros instead of blanks if the value is only one hex digit (the `0`).  If the integer value is too big to fit into two digits, `format` will include three or more characters in the string, which is why I used `& 0xFF` on each integer to ensure that the value will not be too big.  `%02x` does **not** put an `0x` at the front.  The format string has its own `0x` to put those two characters into the result.  (If desired, you can use `%02X` instead of `%02x`, which causes the hex digits A-F to appear in upper case.)

There are other ways: you could create one `int` from the four input integers using `&`, `|` and `<<` bit operators, and use `"0x%08x"` as the format string.  And there are methods besides `String.format` that are capable of generating hex integers.

Comment: thats just it, I'm converting them from integer -> hex. so they may not always be two digits. I'm trying to figure out how to force them to be 2 digits now.

Comment: Well, then, none of the other answers will work either.  I'll work on adding more info.